# Noisy HDMI audio with alsa. Clean audio with pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, amd-graphics

I have this very weird issue when using pure alsa to output the audio via HDMI to my TV monitor.

No matter what buffer_size I put in my custom dmix configuration I can hear random noise popping up while playing some YouTube videos or listening to Spotify.

However, this issue is gone as soon as I switch to pulseaudio.

I’ve tried copying the configuration applied by pulseaudio to the output dmix (buffer_size, fragment_size, etc.) but it did not work at all.

Trying all those snd_hda_intel module parameters also didn’t bring anything.

Do you have any ideas what could be causing this issue?

My PC:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 3700x
- GPU: AMD Radeon RX 5700xt
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Sure, edited my question.